# MPI send struct and recive array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, mpi

I have a problem with communication in my program. The program sends to process  structure and together count search function. I can not properly receive feedback from the search function, which returns an array.

My struct:

```
struct sets{
    int array[R];
};
```

Some struct initialization

```
                tab[0].array[0] = 1;
                tab[0].array[1] = 2;
                tab[0].array[2] = 3;
```

Send information:

```
    obl = calloc(q, sizeof(int));
    MPI_Scatter(tab, q, MPI_INT, obl, q, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    counter = search(tab, setX);
```

And recive and send:

```
if(rank == 0)
    {
        for(i=1; i < p; i++)
        {
            //edit
            MPI_Recv(counter+i, 1, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }

        int k;

        for(k=0; k<N; k++)
        {

            if(*(counter+k) == 5)
            {
                printf("Set number %d is the same \n", k);
            }
            if(*(counter+k) == 1)
            {
                printf("Set number %d have at least one identical \n", k);
            }
            if(*(counter+k) == 2)
            {
                printf("No elements in set number %d \n", k);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MPI_Send(counter, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
```

and search function:

```
int * search(struct sets *tab, int *setX)
{
    int result[N];
    int i; //pass=0

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        result[i]=0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        int j, k;
        int counter=0;

        for(j=0; j<R; j++)
        {
            for(k=0; k<R; k++)
            {
                if(tab[i].array[j] == setX[k])
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }

        //printf("Conuter: %d   -   i: %d \n", counter,i);

            if(counter == R)
            {
                result[i]=5;
                //the same sets
            }
            else if(counter > 1 && counter < R)
            {
                result[i]=1;
                //
            }
            else if(counter == 0)
            {
                result[i]=2;
                //0
            }
        }
    printf("counter: %d\n", counter);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Sequencial run it works ok, but when I run this code on 4 processors result is bad. I think the problem is in send and revice data in MPI functions.

Full code: http://pastebin.com/5c8Jn3sa

EDIT:

Resuts:

./a.out - sequential

```
counter: 10
counter: 9
counter: 0
counter: 10
counter: 6
counter: 6
Set number 0 is the same
Set number 1 have at least one identical
No elements in set number 2
Set number 3 is the same
Set number 4 have at least one identical
Set number 5 have at least one identical
```

mpiecex -np 2 ./a.out - 2 process

```
counter: 100
counter: 100
counter: 100
counter: 100
counter: 100
counter: 100
counter: 10
counter: 9
counter: 0
counter: 10
counter: 6
counter: 6
No elements in set number 0
Set number 1 have at least one identical
Set number 2 have at least one identical
```

mpiexec has a bad results

Comment: Your receives all place the data into the first element of the `counter` array. Either use `MPI_Recv(counter + i, 1, MPI_INT, i, ...);` or `MPI_Gather`.

Comment: I change to `MPI_Recv(conuter + i, 1, MPI_INT, i, ...);` in for loop but still not working.

Comment: Then please update the code and describe *how* it is not working.

Comment: I do this, please check.

Comment: And do you have any solutions?